# Access VBA variables don't seem to clear after sub routine, getting procedure declaration does not match

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database that is used by a production team for performing reviews.  It contains a list of questions, and most questions require an exception be entered if the answer is 'No.'  They are currently updating these fields completely with comboboxes.  I am trying to program it so that after each answer, the portion of the exception that will always be the same based on that answer doesn't have to be updated.  I have started by declaring the variables (both within the sub routine as well as at the top as public variables).  My thought process was that every time they answer a question, the variables would be declared for that specific question and the pop-up form would fill based on those variables.  My code works as expected until I try to add the same code to a different question with the variables changed.  There are a few variables that would always be the same, but I am not concerned with cleaning that up just yet.  My code is below:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public LnNum As Long
Public PCID As Long
Public QCID As String
Public Cat As String
Public ExcDesc As String

Private Sub QCSP15_AfterUpdate()

LnNum = Me.Loan_Number.Value
PCID = Me.PreCloseID.Value
QCID = "QCSP15"
Cat = "Preliminary Application"
ExcDesc = "The initial 1003 was not found in the file."

    If Form_frmPreCloseAudit.QCSP15.Value = "No" Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmTestExceptions"
        DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frmTestExceptions", acNewRec
        Form_frmTestExceptions.Loan_Number.Value = LnNum
        Form_frmTestExceptions.PreClose_ID.Value = PCID
        Form_frmTestExceptions.QCSPID = QCID
        Form_frmTestExceptions.QCSP_Category.Value = Cat
        Form_frmTestExceptions.Exception_Text.Value = ExcDesc
    Else
        DoCmd.GoToControl "QCSP160"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub QCSP154_AfterUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

LnNum = Me.Loan_Number.Value
PCID = Me.PreCloseID.Value
QCID = "QCSP154"
Cat = "Preliminary Application"
ExcDesc = "The DocuSign Certificate of Completion for the initial disclosure package was not uploaded to Doc V."      

     If Form_frmPreCloseAudit.QCSP154.Value = "No" Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmTestExceptions"
        DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frmTestExceptions", acNewRec
        Form_frmTestExceptions.Loan_Number.Value = LnNum
        Form_frmTestExceptions.PreClose_ID.Value = PCID
        Form_frmTestExceptions.QCSPID = QCID
        Form_frmTestExceptions.QCSP_Category.Value = Cat
        Form_frmTestExceptions.Exception_Text.Value = ExcDesc
     Else
        DoCmd.GoToControl "QCSP161"
     End If
End Sub
```

Once I add the second 'After Update' sub procedure for the next question, I get the procedure declaration does not match error.  I have tried naming the variables different things, but nothing seems to work and it might be beyond my ability to figure out as a novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cancel As Integer` is not supported for the *After Update* event.  Remove it from the declaration:

```vb
'Private Sub QCSP154_AfterUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Private Sub QCSP154_AfterUpdate()
```

Avoid that problem in the future by letting Access start you off with a code stub for the event procedure.  Do that from the *Event* tab of the property sheet.  Find the event you want and click the 3-dot icon on the far right side of the adjoining input box.